# jQuery and Bootstrap 3: TypeError: "Object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'preventDefault'

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm working on a page with two Bootstrap 3 modals in Chrome. Everything appears fine until you leave the developer console open and launch one of the modals. You can repeat the issue with this jsfiddle, again with the latest Chrome, or create an html page with the below code.

http://jsfiddle.net/ow3n/22ENG/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function launchReportModal(){
    $('#reportModal').modal();
}
function launchShareModal(){
    $('#shareModal').modal();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<a href='#reportModal' onclick='launchReportModal()' class='report_link' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#reportModal'>report</a>

<a href='#shareModal' onclick='launchShareModal()' class='report_link' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#shareModal'>share</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="reportModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="reportModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">Report <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button></div>
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="shareModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="shareModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">Share <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button></div>
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: Using jQuery selectors to launch the modal in the html fixes the issue, but you can still see the problem in jsfiddle regardless.

```
$('#launchReportModal').on('click', function(){
    $('#reportModal').modal();
});
$('#launchShareModal').on('click', function(){
    $('#shareModal').modal();
});
```

```html
<a href='#' id='launchReportModal' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#reportModal'>report</a>

<a href='#' id='launchShareModal' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#shareModal'>share</a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to activate the modals automatically *and* activate them manually at the same time! If you read the [**docs**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) :

> Activate a modal without writing JavaScript. Set data-toggle="modal"
>   on a controller element, like a button, **along with a
>   data-target="#foo" or href="#foo"** to target a specific modal to
>   toggle.

You have both

```html
<a href='#' id='launchReportModal' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#reportModal'>report</a>
```

and

```js
$('#launchReportModal').on('click', function(){
    $('#reportModal').modal();
});
```

The error is triggered like this :

```js
$.fn.modal (_relatedTarget)
   Modal.toggle (_relatedTarget)
       Modal.hide (_relatedTarget)
```

`_relatedTarget` is considered as an event in the code :

```js
Modal.prototype.hide = function (e) {
    if (e) e.preventDefault()
       -> Uncaught TypeError: Object http://fiddle.jshell.net/22ENG/2/show/# has no method 'preventDefault'
```

But _relatedTarget is not an event, it is an element. Appearently `data-target` has higher rank than your `$(element).modal()` code.

Solution : Just skip your javascript activation of the modals -> **http://jsfiddle.net/QFyv9/** - forked jsFiddle using a unminified version of 3.1.1 bootstrap.js (so I could track down the problem)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. The documentation is unclear that you *shouldn't* use both. I should have noticed the difference using jQuery selectors was a clue. Nice debugging trick to use unminified bootstrap.js as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the jsfiddle demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/22ENG/11/

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and upgraded bootstrap from 3.1.1 to 3.2.0.
The error is gone, and it toggles twice, as coded.